# Joint PDF with graph and variable, problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was given this function:

$\displaystyle f_{X,Y}( x,y) =\begin{cases}
c & in\ the\ area\ of\ the\ picture\\
0 & o.w.
\end{cases}$

The picture is the following:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ispzp.png)

The question is to find $\displaystyle c$, using of course the fact that $\displaystyle \int \int c=1$.

**Their solution:**

They caculated the area geometrically, and said $\displaystyle A=0.5$.

Then, $\displaystyle c=\frac{1}{A} =2$.

I don't undestand too much their solution, why is $\displaystyle c=\frac{1}{A}$? For what reason?

Anyway, my solution was longer, and I occurend into a strange situation.

**My solution:**

Let's divide the ranges of the picures into two areas.

1. $\displaystyle 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$ and $\displaystyle -x+0.5\leqslant y\leqslant -x+1$
2. $\displaystyle 0.5\leqslant x\leqslant 1$ and $\displaystyle -x+1.5\leqslant y\leqslant 1$

I then calculated:

$\displaystyle \int ^{1}_{0}\left(\int ^{-x+1}_{-x+0.5} c\ dy\right) dx\ +\int ^{1}_{0.5}\left(\int ^{1}_{-x+1.5} c\ dy\right) dx\ =\ 1$.

My result was $\displaystyle c=1.6$.

The strange thing is that when I do (notice the difference of $\displaystyle x$ bound in second integral):

$\displaystyle \int ^{1}_{0}\left(\int ^{-x+1}_{-x+0.5} c\ dy\right) dx\ +\int ^{1}_{0}\left(\int ^{1}_{-x+1.5} c\ dy\right) dx\ =\ 1$.

I also get $\displaystyle c=2$.

Same thing as if I did:

$\displaystyle \int ^{1}_{0}\left(\int ^{-x+1}_{-x+0.5} c\ dy+\int ^{1}_{-x+1.5} c\ dy\right) dx=1$.

I don't undestand the difference between these results. It seems to me that in both cases, no matter the change of the $\displaystyle x$ for $\displaystyle 1$ to $\displaystyle 0.5$, the area still represents the same chunk in the picture.

Could anyone explain both the answer in the book, and both the strange behaviour I occured?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given an uniform density (in fact you have $f(x,y)=c$. a constant) in a specific area, that is the colored area in the picture. Thus the density is exactly the reciprocal of the area.

This because your joint distribution is a solid with Base as the area $A$ in the picture and Height constant $c$.

The probability is the volume of the solid figure, thus you have

$$A\times c=1 \rightarrow c=\frac{1}{A}$$

You can integrate the constant in the colored area finding the same result

$$\int_0^{1/2}\left[\int_{1/2-x}^{1-x}dy  \right]dx+\int_{1/2}^1\left[\int_{0}^{1-x}dy  \right]dx+\int_{1/2}^1\left[\int_{3/2-x}^{1}dy  \right]dx=\frac{1}{c}$$

You get $c=2$

Comment: But why isn't my first solution correct? And why is my second solution correct?

Comment: @IamSpano : any integral bounds you showed are incorrect. The fact that in some case the result correspond does not matter. I showed you the correct bounds

Comment: @IamSpano : the fact that in some case you incorrect bounds give a correct result is because the distribution is uniform. If $f(x)$ is not constant any of your integrals will give an incorrect result. As an example, it is enough to integrate in half support to get a correct result

For example

$$\int_0^1\left[\int_0^{1-x}dy\right]dx$$

this is a wrong integral but with correct result.correct result. Your first attempt is wrong AND you have an incorrect result because you do not integrate exactly half of the support

Comment: I get it now, I see how in both the first case and second I should have split the $x$, from the picture my area is incorrect (it goes even under the $y$ axes) thanks!